# RxJS Observable :'Skip is not a function' (or any other function)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am getting a weird error with RxJS, getting a 'Method is not a function'.

I do have import the Observable library.
I already got Observable array with no errors raised.

But when I do a skip, or take,I get this error.

If I read correctly :

> Returns an Observable that skips the first count items emitted by the
>   source Observable.

As my observable contains Article, it should skip x Article on the Observable right?

Here is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Article} from '../../model/article';
import {  ArticleService} from '../../model/article.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-liste-article',
  templateUrl: './liste-article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./liste-article.component.css']
})
export class ListeArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  articles: Observable<Article[]>;
  articlesPage: Observable<Article[]>;
  selectedArticle: Article;
  newArticle: Article;
  page = 1;
  itemPerPage = 2;
  totalItems = 120;

  constructor(private router: Router, private articleService: ArticleService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.articles = this.articleService.getArticles();
    this.articlesPage = this.articles.skip((this.page - 1) * this.itemPerPage ).take(this.itemPerPage);

    //this.articlesPage = this.articles.slice(  (this.page - 1) * this.itemPerPage , (this.page) * this.itemPerPage );

  }
  onSelect(article: Article) {
    this.selectedArticle = article;
    this.router.navigate(['../articles', this.selectedArticle.id ]);
  }
  onPager(event: number): void {
    console.log('Page event is' , event);
    this.page = event;
    this.articlesPage = this.articles.skip((this.page - 1) * this.itemPerPage ).take(this.itemPerPage);

    console.log('tab' , this.articlesPage.count());
    //this.articleService.getArticles().then(articles => this.articles = articles);

  }

  getArticles(): void {
    this.articles = this.articleService.getArticles();
  }
  createArticle(article: Article): void {

    //this.articleService.createArticle(article)
      //.then(articles => {
       // this.articles.push(articles);
       // this.selectedArticle = null;
      //});
  }

  deleteArticle(article: Article): void {
    //this.articleService
     // .deleteArticle(article)
     // .then(() => {
      //  this.articles = this.articles.filter(b => b !== article);
      //  if (this.selectedArticle === article) { this.selectedArticle = null; }
      //});
  }
}
```

I tried to use it directly with `.skip(1)`, but getting the same error.

I checked official documentations [RxJS Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skip) and it looks OK to me. It seems the case is OK, as my call to the function. Both arryas are Observable so I should be able to use those function on one, and put the result in the other one right?

I don't see what is wrong here, probably a small detail, but can't see it myself (as I am starting with this, I see less details).

Comment: My instinct suspects that you should do something like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip` but I may be wrong.

Comment: Indeed. As UncleDave says to. I assumed it was included in the Observable Import.

Comment: Can you share this.articleService.getArticles() code?

Comment: @GiliYaniv the problem has been resolved. The take function doesn't seems to do what I want to (it always take all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to import `skip` and `take` the same way as you have done with `map` and `catch`.

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';`
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Comment: But aren't those function includes in Observable already? That's is why I didn't import them (map and catch are relicate, so I let them here).

Comment: You're specifically importing the observable class:
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

The operators are separate for modularity (and to annoy us).

Comment: I see.Still, disappointing, if you have to import each function you need in your TS file.

Comment: Though this may be late it's about readability and efficiency.
Take example if a new developer were to read your code they would wonder what other functions are available since that one would be just there by default.
Now with the update of pipeable operators this would future encourage the readability and tree shaking of javascript applications that depend on rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

For rxjs@6.5.5 I had to make the following changes:

- import skip

  `import { skip } from "rxjs/operators";`
- change

  `return this.udpstream.asObservable().skip(1);`

  to

  `return this.udpstream.asObservable().pipe(skip(1));`